# PyOpenCL and Mesa Radeon driver

Tags: gentoo, radeon

I'm trying to run pyopencl with the open source radeon drivers on gentoo. The package compiles fine, but every time I try to import the pyopencl module, I get an error telling me that the clGetExtensionFunctionAddress symbol cannot be found in _cl.so (and the libraries this is linked to). This function is indeed defined in the header files installed by mesa (cl.h), yet it seems to be missing from the actual library.
OpenCL itself seens to be working, it's just pyopencl that refuses to load. Since I need pyopencl for my current project, for the moment I'm using fglrx, but I'd really prefer to use pyopencl with the open source driver which imho performs much better for everyday work.

I was trying to use mesa 9.2.2 and pyopencl 2013.2.

To sum it up: How can I get pyopencl running with the open source radeon drivers?

Comment: Open source drivers don't support OpenCL, you'll have to install proprietary drivers.

Comment: I was just wondering, since mesa installs OpenCL libraries and headers, and I stumbled across following article: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0ODY
That made me a little bit too optimistic, I guess, since now I managed to get more relevant information: http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/GalliumCompute/ Obviously, although bitcoin mining works, the OpenCL implementation is still quite a bit from being complete... I guess I really have to stay with fgrlx for the moment. But hopefully not for too long ;-)

Comment: Hmmmm...now that is interesting :P I lately I haven't pay many attention on the state of open source drivers and openCL...guess a lot has changed already, thanks to bitcoinsXD